# After get data javascript will stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to get data from input options and text fields and insert to table.

I did it with javascript and jquery but after insert data to table so after execution of function dataSend my javascript will stop working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variables
  var status = $(".status");
  var comment = $(".comments");
  var questionsVal;
  var statusVal = "test";
  var commentsVal = "test2";

  function dataSend() {
    var inputText = jQuery('input[type="text"]');
    var inputRadio = jQuery('input[type="radio"]');
    var i = -1;
    var i2 = -1;
    while (i < inputText.length - 1) {
      i++;
      comment[i].innerHTML = inputText.eq(i).val();
    }
    console.log("test1");
    while (i2 < inputRadio.length - 1) {
      i2++;
      status[i2].innerHTML = inputRadio.eq(i2).val();
    }
    console.log("test2");
  }

  jQuery("#dataSend").click(function() {
    dataSend();
    console.log("ok");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dataExport">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Questions</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>First question</td>
        <td class="status"></td>
        <td class="comments"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>Second question</td>
        <td class="status"></td>
        <td class="comments"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>Third question</td>
        <td class="status"></td>
        <td class="comments"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="questions">
  <div>
    <h4>First question</h4>
    <form>
      <p>Choose 1 option</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="ok" checked="checked"> Ok<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="error"> Error<br><br>
      <p>Comment</p>
      <input type="text" name="comment1" value="Comment1">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Second question</h4>
    <form>
      <p>Choose 1 option</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="ok"> Ok<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="error" checked="checked"> Error<br><br>
      <p>Comment</p>
      <input type="text" name="comment2" value="Comment2">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Third question</h4>
    <form>
      <p>Choose 1 option</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="ok" checked="checked"> Ok<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="error"> Error<br><br>
      <p>Comment</p>
      <input type="text" name="comment3" value="Comment3">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="dataSend">Send data to table</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my code you can see console test1, test2, ok.

I can not get test2 and ok.

Here you can see this in codepen: https://codepen.io/soorta/pen/gOYLpYq?editors=1111

Thank You for help.

Comment: You are accessing `status[i2]` where `i2==3`. You have exceeded the bounds of your array

Comment: U sure @LeeTaylor? `i2` is initialized to -1?

Comment: @radarbob - Quite sure. I stepped through the code. i2 is set to -1 but then i2++ happens...

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you have more radio input elements than status element, which will cause issues when iterating each radio element to update the corresponding `.status` element.

Consider updating this line to select on those radio input elements that are `:checked` to ensure that there is one radio element per status element:

```
var inputRadio = jQuery('input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

A few other suggestions to consider with your script would be;

- rather than access the result of a jquery selection like this `[i]` when updating an element, consider using the `.eq(i)` approach as you have done for accessing data from the input elements (ie `comment.eq(i).` and `status.eq(i2)`)
- instead of setting the `innerHTML` of the selected jquery element, you could instead set the text content of the element via `.text()` (ie `comment.eq(i).text("content");`)
- return `false` from the buttons click handler to prevent the button click invoking a page reload

Here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variables
  var status = $(".status");
  var comment = $(".comments");
  var questionsVal;
  var statusVal = "test";
  var commentsVal = "test2";

  function dataSend() {
    var inputText = jQuery('input[type="text"]');
    var inputRadio = jQuery('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    var i = -1;
    var i2 = -1;
    while (i < inputText.length - 1) {
      i++;
      comment.eq(i).text(inputText.eq(i).val());
    }
    console.log("test1");
    while (i2 < inputRadio.length - 1) {
      i2++;
      status.eq(i2).text(inputRadio.eq(i2).val());
    }
    console.log("test2");
  }



  jQuery("#dataSend").click(function() {
    dataSend();

    console.log("ok");
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 100px 50px 100px;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30px;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60px;
}

th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 300px;
}

div#questions {
  margin-left: 70px;
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

div#questions div {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#questions div:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

div#buttons button {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dataExport">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Questions</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>First question</td>
        <td class="status"></td>
        <td class="comments"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>Second question</td>
        <td class="status"></td>
        <td class="comments"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>Third question</td>
        <td class="status"></td>
        <td class="comments"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>


<div id="questions">
  <div>
    <h4>First question</h4>
    <form>
      <p>Choose 1 option</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="ok" checked="checked"> Ok<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="error"> Error<br><br>
      <p>Comment</p>
      <input type="text" name="comment1" value="Comment1">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Second question</h4>
    <form>
      <p>Choose 1 option</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="ok"> Ok<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="error" checked="checked"> Error<br><br>
      <p>Comment</p>
      <input type="text" name="comment2" value="Comment2">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Third question</h4>
    <form>
      <p>Choose 1 option</p>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="ok" checked="checked"> Ok<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question3" value="error"> Error<br><br>
      <p>Comment</p>
      <input type="text" name="comment3" value="Comment3">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="dataSend">Send data to table</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Update

Just to expand on the reason for returning `false` from the click handler. When you return `false` from a handler, this [tells jQuery to stop the browsers default behavior for that event](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Callback) relating to that element.

In the case of your code, the `<button>` element has default "browser behavior" of submitting form data to the server which will trigger a page reload. By returning `false` from the click handler that you've assigned to that button, this informs jQuery to prevent that submit-and-reload behavior from occouring.

Comment: @radarbob the codepen doesn't seem to work for me. ie, setting radio button second questions to "Ok" still reads "error" in the table after clicking "send data to table"

Comment: Let me correct myself. Upon actual investigation "Seems to work" because the CodePen Console is a POS and I was lazy. *Using the browser's Console* reveals an error message.

Comment: I am grateful for your advice, but still I don't understand why to use there "return false"  . I am new in javascript so I don't understand everything. Do you have any good sample when to use return and when not? Thank You

Comment: @Tomas not a problem - just updated the answer with extra detail on that under the *Update* heading. Does that help?

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the grey arrow if it answered your questions